# Why do I need to a localGroup:insert( object ) with the corona director class?

Tags: mobile, lua, coronasdk

I cant seem to wrap my head around the localGroup:insert command that is necessary when using the director class.

If I create my object with something like:

```
local btnBegin = display.newImage( "images/btn_begin.png", (display.viewableContentWidth/2)-200, display.contentHeight * .7 )
```

The image will display perfectly fine in the scene, even if I never do a

```
localGroup:insert( btnBegin )
```

I would have thought that the localGroup:insert would be necessary so that all of the components of the scene can be grouped to gether for the display, but isnt that the point of

```
function new()
```

at the begining of each scene? In my mind, I see it that creating all of my objects within the function already makes them local to the scene file. What does  localGroup:insert accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you could have a HUD which you add straight to the screen and the localGroup containing your level. Then if you change level, you would only move away the level contained in the localGroup and keep the elements of the HUD you placed straight on the screen.

Comment: So the elements outside of the localGroup are not change with the scene?

Comment: Yes indeed, that is how I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

When you do **display.newImage(...)** this adds the display object to the main stage. As tomdemuyt has said, this might be useful for a HUD or some other graphics that appear between scenes.

The stage also contains your scene, defined here has **localGroup**. To add an object to your scene, you should insert it into the localGroup.

This is useful for example, if you have a menu scene containing menu buttons. If you press the "start game" button, when the screen transitions to the next scene all your menu items will be removed appropriately with the menu scene, instead of hanging around on the global stage.

It all comes down to the display hierarchy and how you want to organize it. It makes sense to have sub objects inserted into their appropriate parents:

1. the stage **HAS A** menu scene
2. the menu scene **HAS A** button

Makes more sense than:

1. the stage **HAS A** menu scene
2. the stage **HAS A** button